# Bing WPF adding labels to pushpins

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bing

I'm trying to add labels to my Pushpins, and I'm experimenting with two different ways to add the pushpin to the map.

Test 1 is from the xaml code, I can add the pushpin but I can't figure out how to add text

Test 2 is from the C# code, when I try to open the map I get an error of "Object refernce not set to an instance of an object on the line "myMap.Children.Add(pin);"

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFKiosk.MapWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

         xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"

        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFKiosk"

        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MapWindow" Height="910" Width="1080" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <!-- -->
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplate" TargetType="m:Pushpin">
            <Image x:Name="pinImage" Height="64" Source="/Images/Push_Pin.png"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Width="1080" Height="915">

        <m:Map x:Name="myMap" CredentialsProvider="My_Key" Mode="Road">

            <m:Pushpin Location="28,-81"/>
            <!-- Test 1 -->
        </m:Map>

        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="510,740,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Images/iTO Back Arrow.png" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Design;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Core;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Overlays;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WPFKiosk
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MapWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MapWindow : Window
    {
        private DispatcherTimer closeTimer;

        public MapWindow()
        {
            Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
            pin.Location = new Location(28.5383, -81.3792);
            pin.Content = "text";
            pin.Template = (ControlTemplate)(this.Resources["PushpinControlTemplate"]);
            myMap.Children.Add(pin);
            //Test 2

            this.Left = 0;
            this.Top = 0;
            this.Topmost = true;

            InitializeComponent();

            LocationConverter locConverter = new LocationConverter();
            // Setting the map view... aka Zoom level and center of zoom
            // A string of the coordinates of a location is required
            String OrlandoLoc = "28.5383,-81.3792,0.0";
            // The String is then converted to a location that the map can interpret
            Location center = (Location)locConverter.ConvertFrom(OrlandoLoc);
            myMap.SetView(center, 13);

            closeTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            closeTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            closeTimer.Tick += CloseTimer_Tick;
            closeTimer.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `myMap` variable is assigned when `InitialiseComponent` is called. Move the line `myMap.Children.Add(pin);` after `InitialiseComponent`

Comment: Thank you! Of course it was something as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

Pushpin is a ContentControl, so you may add whatever Content you like:

```
<m:Pushpin Location="28,-81" Content="Hello"/>
```

or

```
<m:Pushpin Location="28,-81">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
</m:Pushpin>
```

or any more complex Content like

```
<m:Pushpin Location="28,-81">
    <Image Source="..."/>
</m:Pushpin>
```

Comment: That works, but do you know how to make the text not be squished inside the pin?

Comment: You would certainly need a different ControlTemplate, i.e. `<m:Pushpin ... Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplate}"/>`. Even better might be a default Pushpin Style that would set the Template property.